# can I charge 2 batteries in series

Tags: series

Can I charge two lithium ion batteries connected in series? What is more efficient, series or parallel in terms of charging?

Thank you for answering this question.

Comment: What happens if one gets hot?

Comment: Are you using a suitable balancing circuit?

Comment: Are you designing the charger ?

Comment: I am trying to charge 2 18650 lithium batteries directly into a supply. (Not in a 220v AC)

Answer (score 1):

I  would  be cautious   when  charging  these   batteries   I would think these  batteries  should   each have  their   own   individual   circuit   with   designs   to closely   monitor   current  and also  means to   monitor   battery  temperature  and  finally   cell   voltage